# Why my clipboard can only paste out from RDP into my desktop not the other way around?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-xp, remote, windows-terminal-services

I'm having very weird problem in my TS RDP connection,

I can copy and paste from my TS RDP out into my desktop (from any program into any program in my home workstation)

but somehow I cannot copy paste from my desktop into my TS RDP (from any program at all - it always remember the old content of the clipboard) ?

this is going through RDP session over Juniper SSL VPN  into the Windows Server 2003 Terminal Server but obviously this is the same TS RDP application that is provided by Windows.

any help regarding this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Go to Administrative Tools | Terminal Services Configuration. Right-click on RDP-TCP | Properties. Under the client settings tab, make sure "clipboard mapping" isn't checked.

Answer (score 2):

On the 2003 server box, if you go to Administrative Tools | Terminal Services | Terminal Services Configuration right click on the "RDP-Tcp" connection in the Connections list and choose properties and then go to the Client Settings tab. Is the Clipboard option checked? If it is, uncheck it.

I have encountered weirdness like this from time to time, but rebooting my client machine usually solves it. If this is a consistent issue with this server it is likely a TS configuration issue.

Comment: why i need to unchecked it ? should it be checked to enable it ?

Comment: I've always found that very confusing too. The problem is that when you open up the RDP client it also has the option to sync the clipboard and I believe that is enabled by default when you open up mstsc and try to connect to a machine. 

The MSDN article on terminal services (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770631%28WS.10%29.aspx) indicates that disabling the checkbox on the server side will disable all clipboard sharing even if the RDP client has the option enabled, but I have never found that to be the case.

Comment: ah yes, thanks for your reply mate, I am now able to make it works after restarting the whole terminal server.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the Rdpclip.exe (RDP Clipboard) Process in Windows, go to Task manager, Users Tab, expand processes of the user you have problem, and right click on RDP Clipboard Monitor, then "End task", disconnect and reconnect and clipboard will work two ways again.